# Implement worker with RabbitMQ Consumer

Tags: php, rabbitmq, worker

What are the consequences of doing this:

```
public function execute(AMQPMessage $message)
{
    while (true) {
        // Do some heavy work here (Example: retrieve the last 50 items from the database and update their states, etc)

        sleep(2); // Sleep for 2 seconds
    }

    return true; // Acknowledge (Never executed)
}
```

1. One unacknowledged message (Bad)
2. Max execution time of PHP script (But, it works perfectly and is never ending even though phpinfo shows 60 seconds)
3. Any more issues

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear if you are asking for help with a problem (good) or asking someone to check your code for (bad)

Comment: OK, maybe I am missing something, but the behavior described in your post is exactly what you wrote here. `while(true)` with no `return` statement is a never-ending loop.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I am asking a question and it can help many other developers who are stuck on this (because I have seen a lot of questions like this which are not answered yet).

Comment: If I had wanted to solve my own problem, I would have written my own code here. But, I wrote a simple code so that others also can benefit from it. That's a purpose of stackoverflow.

Comment: And the title of the question is "Implement worker with RabbitMQ Consumer". I didn't ask a question "How to implement a worker with RabbitMQ" which is too broad. I provided the code which I tested and it worked. I am just asking about the issues that may happen which I am not aware of.